# Is parsing a string in the onTick method crashing my app?

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I have a short CountDownTimer (3 seconds long at minimum, 10 at max) that I'm using to control when a new math problem is displayed on the screen. Every 1 second, the CountDownTimer should check if the user has entered the correct answer in an EditText. Here is the code I have for it:

```
private void startQuestionTimer()
    {
        long startTime = DataHolder.getQuestionTime()*1000;
        questionTimer = new CountDownTimer(startTime, 1000) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                //continually check user's input into the EditText
                //if input is ever equal to actualIntAnswer, reset the timer and EditText
                //then display another math problem
                int givenAnswer = Integer.parseInt(userAnswer.getText().toString());
                if (givenAnswer == actualIntAnswer)
                {
                    questionTimer.cancel();
                    userAnswer.getText().clear();
                    displayNewMathProblem();
                    questionTimer.start();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                displayNewMathProblem();
                if (!testTimeExpired)
                {
                    questionTimer.start();
                }
                else
                {
                    questionTimer.cancel();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
```

The problem I'm having is that the app crashes as soon as this CountDownTimer is created. For some reason, `int givenAnswer = Integer.parseInt(userAnswer.getText().toString());` seems to crash the app, and I think it's because the CountDownTimer cannot do all that in just 1 second. I tried splitting it into 2 methods like so:

```
private int givenAnswer;
private String givenAnswerToString()
    {
        return userAnswer.getText().toString();
    }

    private void givenAnswerToInt()
    {
        givenAnswer = Integer.parseInt(givenAnswerToString());
    }
```

And then calling to givenAnswerToInt() in onTick() like so:

```
@Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                givenAnswerToInt();
                if (givenAnswer == actualIntAnswer)
                {
                    questionTimer.cancel();
                    userAnswer.getText().clear();
                    displayNewMathProblem();
                    questionTimer.start();
                }

            }
```

Here is the error message I get when the CountDownTimer is created:
[image]

What's going on here? Is it an issue of trying to do too many things in a short amount of time like I think it is, or is it something else entirely? What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Hello! Are you getting a `NumberFormatException`?

Comment: How is `userAnswer` obtained/initialized?

Comment: You need to post minimal, _**reproducible**_ code. There are variables that we have no idea how they were initialized. Also, what is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: @hfontanez userAnswer is a number (signed) EditText that's empty by default. It does have a hint that says "Enter your answer".

Comment: @Nicola I looked through the logcat and I did see that appear in there.

Comment: Your code lacks details that prevent us from running your code. We don't even know the exact error. You need to update your post with missing details.

Comment: The logcat is usually used for debugging. A message about what caused your app to abruptly end would usually be visible in the Run screen (if you're using Android Studio). You should include that to your question together with a reproducible piece of code. That would increase the clarity of your question and, especially, the probability that someone could answer it.

Comment: @Nicola My mistake, it was in the run screen, not logcat. I've included a picture of the error message, which I think is the same one you asked if I was getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Integer.parseInt`](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_try_catch.asp) can throw a `NumberFormatException` which would cause the application to stop abruptly if not caught.
This happens when the `String` that you're passing as parameter of `parseInt` isn't recognized as a decimal number.
The fact that this happens almost instantaneously in your code is due to the fact that the `EditText.getText().toString()` is just returning `""`, since the user has not typed any number in the widget.
What you can do is simply manage the exception with a [`try-catch`](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_try_catch.asp) statement:

```
int givenAnswer = 0; // initialize accordingly with your needs
try {
    givenAnswer = Integer.parseInt(userAnswer.getText().toString());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // return or do something else to deal with the problem
}

if(givenAnswer == actualIntAnswer){
    ...
}
...
```